# bash: /usr/bin/autoreconf: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: perl, msys2, msys, pacman-package-manager, autoreconf

I am trying to compile some software in Windows using ***MSYS2 mingw64.exe*** terminal.

On running the `autoreconf -i` command, I get the error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/autoreconf: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

`ls /usr/bin/` doesn't show perl.exe

I remember that `perl` was installed using some `pacman -S` command.

As far as I remember, this issue has come up since this month.
(I had reinstalled MSYS2 and Pacman packages thrice this month & the issue does not seem to go. Last time, I had installed all these in May this year & there were no such issues then)

I even re-installed perl in Msys2 and the following output is displayed:

```
$ pacman -S perl
warning: perl-5.30.3-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) perl-5.30.3-1

Total Installed Size:  50.67 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                                      [####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                                    [####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                         [####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                                   [####################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                                                 [####################################################################] 100%
warning: could not get file information for usr/bin/perl.exe
warning: could not get file information for usr/bin/perl5.30.3.exe
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling perl                                                                                             [####################################################################] 100%
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/bin/perl.exe (Can't create '/usr/bin/perl.exe')
warning: warning given when extracting /usr/bin/perl5.30.3.exe (Hard-link target 'usr/bin/perl.exe' does not exist.)
```

Still, the same issue `-bash: /usr/bin/autoreconf: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` appears

I also tried installing older version(5.28) of perl by:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-perl mingw-w64-x86_64-perl
```

Still the same issue

On further observation, I found out that the perl was getting installed in /mingw64/bin directory instead of /usr/bin.
I tried adding /mingw64/bin directory to the PATH variable as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/mingw64/bin"
```

However, the issue is still the same

Please help

Comment: Can you create a symlink?: `cd /usr/bin && ln -s /mingw64/bin/perl.exe`

Comment: @Georg Mavridis, on running this, I got the error ```ln: failed to create symbolic link './perl.exe': Permission denied```

Comment: Also, on trying the same command with sudo, I got the error ```-bash: sudo: command not found
```